# Framework for Genetic Algorithms on python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithms

I'm trying to use a framework implemented in python to use GA (Genetic algorithms) and other related algorithms . But I'm not sure about what framework to use, I've found two interesting options Pymoo and JmetalPy, the former it seems well documented it and the latter isn't looks like it (it's under construction), but the version in Java is very popular and well know. I need choose a framework to make a comparation with an algorithm made by me.

For this reason a reliable framework is needed and with small learning curve.

Do you have any good or  bad experience using it?,
Do you know another framework?

Pymoo:
[Paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9078759?denied=)
[Docs](https://pymoo.org/)

JmetalPy: [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02915)
[Docs](https://jmetal.github.io/jMetalPy/index.html)

Comment: @noe I really find interesting  your answer, I'll read the docs for that framework,  seems to be what I'm looking for.